# Can I ignore the text length in SQL Server full text search

Tags: sql, full-text-search

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestFTS]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [FTS] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL,  

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TestFTS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
```

I added full text search index on FTS column and fill it with the following data

[image]

When I try to run this query

```
SELECT [Key], [RANK] * 10 rank, 1, N'1' 
FROM CONTAINSTABLE(TestFTS, FTS, '  FORMSOF(THESAURUS, "PS5") OR  FORMSOF(THESAURUS, "with") OR FORMSOF(THESAURUS, "joystics") ', language 1033)
```

I got this result

[image]

There is a difference between the ranks and I think this because the second row is longer than the first one.

The question is: can I ignore the text length in SQL Server full text search or there is another way to get the same rank for both?

Thanks